# Minimize Reprojection Error

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear

I have a function

```
Point= {2, 0, 0, 1};
x = ProjectionMatrix[f] . (RotateMatrix . Point + t)
Return[x];
x is a 3D Vector.
```

where the Projection Matrix is

```
ProjektionsMatrix[f1_] := {{f1, 0, 3, 0}, {0, f1, 5, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}};
```

and the RotateMatrix is a Rotation Matrix with Rotation: D(x, alpha).D(y, beta).D(z, gamma).

```
alpha = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[6 Degree], -Sin[6 Degree], 0}, {0, Sin[6 Degree], Cos[6 Degree], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
beta =  {{Cos[9 Degree], 0, Sin[9 Degree], 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {-Sin[9 Degree], 0, Cos[9 Degree], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}; 
gamam = {{Cos[14 Degree], -Sin[14 Degree], 0, 0}, {Sin[14 Degree], Cos[14 Degree], 0, 0}, {0,0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
RotateMatrix = alpha.beta.gamma;
```

and I have an Result Point given:

```
(8.12033)
(6.37024)
(1.     )
```

I want to find a value for f, so the the Result of the Function x and the Result Point is minimized.

I tried the mathematica Function FindMinimum of the Norm from this points.

```
FindMinimum[(MinimizeFunction[func] - ResultPoint).(MinimizeFunction[func] - ResultPoint)], 
        {func, 2}];
```

But there's no solution for this f.
I also tried Nminimize but it doesn't worked.

Can somebody help me to find a function to minimize the Result with values for f?
I wanted to use the Levenberg Marquart Method to Minimize this function.

So the full minimize Function ist:

````
MinimizeFunction[f_] := Module[{alpha, beta, gamma},
    alpha = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[6 Degree], -Sin[6 Degree], 0}, {0, Sin[6 Degree], Cos[6 Degree], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
    beta =  {{Cos[9 Degree], 0, Sin[9 Degree], 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {-Sin[9 Degree], 0, Cos[9 Degree], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}; 
    gamma = {{Cos[14 Degree], -Sin[14 Degree], 0, 0}, {Sin[14 Degree], Cos[14 Degree], 0, 0}, {0,0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
    Drehmatrix = alp.bet.gam;
    UrPoint= {2, 0, 0, 1};
t = {0,0,1};
    ProjektionsMatrix[f1_] := {{f1, 0, 3, 0}, {0, f1, 5, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}};
    temp = ProjektionsMatrix[f] . ((Drehmatrix . UrPoint) + t);
    temp = temp/temp[[3]];
    Return[temp];
];


ResultPoint= {8.12033,6.37024,1};
FindMinimum[
        ((MinimizeFunction[func] - ResultPoint).(MinimizeFunction[func] - ResultPoint)) = 0, 
        {func, 1}];
```
````

Comment: Your code is incomplete and doesn't evaluate! Please show Mathematica code for `ProjectionMatrix` and `RotateMatrix`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to change the algorithm:

```
temp = temp/temp[[3]];
temp = (MinimizeFunction[func] - ResultPoint).(MinimizeFunction[func] - ResultPoint)
Return[temp];

FindMinimum[MinimizeFunction, f];
```